# Laravel 4 MethodNotAllowedhttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException when I submit the form detailed below.  The route appears correct to me and is syntactically the same as other post routes that are working just fine.  The controller method exists but even so I think the exception is occuring before the request gets to the controller as item 4 on the left of the laravel error page says handleRoutingException right after item 3 which says findRoute.  I am pretty sure I am not using restful routing the way you should in laravel 4 but that is because the tutorial I am following a laravel 3 tutorial and updating hte syntax to 4 as I go but like I said the other routes work fine so I can't figure out why this one isn't.

Template

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
<div id="ask">
    <h1>Ask a Question</h1>

    @if(Auth::check())
        @include('_partials.errors')

        {{ Form::open(array('ask', 'POST')) }}

        {{ Form::token() }}

        <p>
            {{ Form::label('question', 'Question') }}
            {{ Form::text('question', Input::old('question')) }}

            {{ Form::submit('Ask a Question') }}

        </p>

        {{ Form::close() }}
    @else

    <p>

        <p>Please login to ask or answer questions.</p>

    </p>
    @endif



</div><!-- end ask -->
@stop
```

Route

```
Route::post('ask', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'QuestionsController@post_create'));
```

Controller

```
<?php

class QuestionsController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;
    protected $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('post_create'));
    }

    public function get_index() {
        return View::make('questions.index')
            ->with('title', 'Make It Snappy Q&A - Home');
    }

    public function post_create()
    {
        $validation = Question::validate(Input::all());

        if($validation->passes()) {
            Question::create(array(
                'question'=>Input::get('question'),
                'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id
            ));

            return Redirect::Route('home')
            ->with('message', 'Your question has been posted.');

        } else {
            return Redirect::Route('register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
        }
    }


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe defining `public $restful = true;` is how it was done in Laravel 3.  In Laravel 4 you define a restful controller in your routes like so:

```
Route::controller('ask', 'QuestionsController');
```

Then to define the functions you would not use an underscore to separate them.  You must use camel case like so:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    // go buck wild...
}

public function postCreate() 
{
    // do what you do...
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you both I will go back and re write my routes correctly with the laravel 4 methods and see how I get on.

Answer (score 1):

For [RESTful Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) you should define the `route` using `Route::controller` method, i.e.

```
Route::controller('ask', 'QuestionsController');
```

and `controller methods` should be prefixed with `http verb` that it responbds to, for example, you may use `postCreate` and you have `post_create` instead, so it doesn't look like a `Restful` controller.

You are using `public $restful = true;` in your controller, this is not being used in `Laravel-4`, and `public $restful = true;` may causing the problem, so remove this line.